# How to perform search on list of objects using multiple parameters?

Tags: c#

I have `List<>` of objects with type of my class `Car`. Class `Car` has 12 attributes. And I have 7 `TextBox` where user can enter there search values (some of attributes). How do I search trough this list to get objects which match all data entered?
I've tried something like this:

```
foreach (Car x in Cars)
{
   //then here I question every attribute with search value which match I add to new List<>
   if(x.color == textBox1.Text) search.Add(x); 
}
```

`textBox1` is one of values user enters. This works when user enters only one value. If I enter two values it finds all objects with any of that two values. But I want to find objects which match both of values.

Comment: `Cars.Where(x => x.Property1 == "Value" && x.Property2 == "Value2")`...? If you're looking for something more generic I would add an example of your `Car` class and what data types it contains.

Comment: How do these 7 textboxes map to the 12 attributes? Do you mean the user can arbitrarily enter values of any attributes in any textbox in any order to search? I think in the first place I would advise you revise your design as it doesn't sound easy to understand/user-friendly. I would advise you put specific fields for specific attributes. This way you can do type checks, auto complete, provide a list of values, ...etc. If space is the concern, then you can employ some smart UI organization to fit the elements (e.g. show a button "Color" to enable the color filter)

Comment: @Neptune Actually they are `combobox` but i tough this would be easier to explain.

Comment: Does each combobox correspond to one specific attribute? i.e. you search for just 7 of the 12 overall attributes?

Comment: If that's the case then you can use LINQ composition as shown in the answers below. You start with a list and add "Where" statements to add conditions and then materialize the Queryable at the end (e.g. calling .ToList() on it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to check if the filter value is entered do this

```
IEnumerable<Car> filteredCars = Cars;

if(!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textBox1.Text))
   filteredCars = filteredCars.Where(car=>car.param == textBox1.Text);

if(!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textBox2.Text))
   filteredCars = filteredCars.Where(car=>car.param2 == textBox2.Text);
```

And finally

```
var result = filteredCars.ToList()
```

execute `ToList` just one time (at the end)

Comment: This implies that every filter should have a value otherwise if for example the car has a color and user is looking for the constructor no result will be returned

Comment: Stills quite confusing, so you want it to end up with 12 conditions ?

Comment: Why do you check for the value of a `filter` variable not being null, but then compare against the literal string `"filter"`? Ahem... what?

Comment: checking if the string is null is just an exemple.

Comment: Are you trying to say that it is okay that the code in your answer is being nonsensical because it is "just" an example?

Comment: @SoufianeTahiri, Yes he shoud check every filter, if it is entered then add it to the where

Comment: @elgonzo , the question is how to apply all entered filters, concerning the strings checking is up to him, because I don't know if they are string.empty or null by default,

Comment: Can you please explain your code sample to me, because i don't see any meaning in it. Why does your Linq Where query compare against the literal string `"filter"`? And why would comparing against this literal string require a check whether some other variable is null or not? Can you please take a look at your own code in your answer before commenting again?

Comment: @elgonzo, I edited the code, check if it is clear now. thanks

Comment: Alright. Makes much more sense now. Thanks for making your answer clearer... :-)

Comment: @Pliskin I'm getting this error: `Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)` on filteredCars.Where(car=>car.param == textBox1.Text);

Comment: @DaniloIvanovic replace the first line with this var filteredCars = Cars.ToList();

Comment: @Pliskin No still the same.

Answer (score 0):

## Using Reflection Magic

I guess you want a result like this?

[image: Demonstration]

I havn't auto-generated the `TextBox`es, but that is pretty easy.

MainWindow.xaml

```
<StackPanel x:Name="MainGrid" Width="200" Margin="100">
    <TextBlock Text="Color" />
    <TextBox x:Name="ColorTextBox"></TextBox>
    <TextBlock Text="Make" />
    <TextBox x:Name="MakeTextBox"></TextBox>
    <TextBlock Text="Interior" />
    <TextBox x:Name="InteriorTextBox"></TextBox>
    <Button x:Name="SearchButton" Content="Search" Click="SearchButton_Click"></Button>
    <TextBlock x:Name="SearchResultTextBlock"></TextBlock>
</StackPanel>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
private void SearchButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Car[] allCars = new Car[] // Sample list of cars
    {
        new Car
        {
            Color = "Green",
            Make = "Ford",
            Interior = "Stone"
        },
        new Car
        {
            Color = "Green",
            Make = "Ford",
            Interior = "Wood"
        },
        new Car
        {
            Color = "Black",
            Make = "Cadillac",
            Interior = "Stone"
        },
        new Car
        {
            Color = "Black",
            Make = "Volvo",
            Interior = "Stone"
        },
        new Car
        {
            Color = "Green",
            Make = "Volvo",
            Interior = "Wood"
        },
        new Car
        {
            Color = "Green",
            Make = "Volvo",
            Interior = "Plastic"
        },
    };

    var result = _filterWithInputs(allCars); // Search the list

    SearchResultTextBlock.Text = $"Found {result.Length} matching cars."; // Output
}

private Car[] _filterWithInputs(IEnumerable<Car> allCars)
{
    List<Car> result = new List<Car>();

    // Get the TextBoxes from the viow
    List<TextBox> textBoxes = new List<TextBox>();
    foreach (var mainGridChild in MainGrid.Children)
    {
        if(mainGridChild is TextBox)
            textBoxes.Add(mainGridChild as TextBox);
    }

    // Search the allCars collection.
    foreach (var car in allCars)
    {
        if (_checkCarAgainstNamedTextBoxes(car, textBoxes))
            result.Add(car);
    }

    Debug.WriteLine($"Found {result.Count} matching cars.");

    // Return the result as a fixed-size array.
    return result.ToArray();
}

private static bool _checkCarAgainstNamedTextBoxes(Car car, IEnumerable<TextBox> textBoxes)
{
    foreach (TextBox textBox in textBoxes)
    {
        // Skip empty TextBokes (succees)
        if(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textBox.Text))
            continue;

        var propertyName = textBox.Name.Replace("TextBox", "");

        // Assume all Car properties are strings
        var val = car.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName)?.GetValue(car) as string;

        // If the text doesn't match (case-sesitive) return false
        // No need to check any more properties after first fail.
        if (val != textBox.Text)
            return false;
    }

    return true; // Everything succeeded!
}
```

The magic happens in `_checkCarAgainstNamedTextBoxes` where the prefix of the TextBokes is compared to the property names of the Car class.

If a `TextBox` is named `ColorTextBox` its value will be compared to the `Color` property of the car.

The textboxes must be directly under the `MainGrid` to show up in the "Children" collection. Recursion is easy to search multiple levels.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a list of your paramater values that can handle null, and execute in a single query:

```
string color = String.IsNullOrEmpty(textColor.Text) ? null : textColor.Text;
string engine = String.IsNullOrEmpty(textEngine.Text) ? null : textEngine.Text;

var filteredList = cars.Where(c => (color == null || c.Color == color) &&
                                   (engine == null || c.Engine == engine)).ToList();
```

Do the same thing for the other text boxes.

Answer (score -1):

When you use LINQ, you can progressively extend your query based on the selected criteria:

```
var carsQry =
    from car in Cars
    select car;

//Filter by color
if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textBox1.Text)) {
    carsQry =
        from car in carsQry
        where cars.color == textBox1.Text.Trim()
        select car;
}

//...repeat step above for all other filter criteria...

List<Car> filteredCars = carsQry.ToList();
```

This works because you can modify a LINQ query until you materialize it. In this case you add all of the selected filter criteria *before* you actually execute it. As a last step you materialize (=execute) it with `ToList`. The returned list will contain your filtered items.

Comment: Too much code for the same result as LINQ where function

Comment: @Dude, this is LINQ query syntax. It's exactly the same amount of code, which you have just copied and transformed into method syntax.